# Execute script on remote mysql db?

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file, database-administration

I'm using below script to update a table in mysql db which is installed in my local machine.

### update.sql

```
use test;
update test.stockcurrent set units='0' where units<'0';
```

### update.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MYSQL_EXE="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe"
SET DB_USER=root
SET DB_PWD=password

CALL %MYSQL_EXE% --user=%DB_USER% --password=%DB_PWD% < update.sql
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO Error executing SQL file
```

**Above code is working fine** in **if mysql is running locally** in my machine.

**But Now I need to connect to mysql which is running remotely and I need to execute the script from my local machine**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your script as per below, need to add -h  in your script.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MYSQL_EXE="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe"
SET DB_USER=root
SET DB_PWD=password

CALL %MYSQL_EXE% -h <your_server_ip> --user=%DB_USER% --password=%DB_PWD% < update.sql >> C:\log\error.txt 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO Error executing SQL file
```

Note: user should have rights on remote server from your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My local machine should have mysql.exe?

Comment: yes mysql.exe utility should be in your machine at the path as you mentioned in your script.

Comment: even you can keep this utility at any path and change that path in your script.

Comment: But I should not install any mysql stuff in my local machine. How can I connect to remote mysql and run commands without installing mydql utility locally?

Comment: just copy mysql.exe from any other machine where mysql installed and copy at the path you mentioned in script. it will work. Without this client you can't connect remote server.

Comment: Ok. Will I come to know whether commands are executed successfully on the console?

Comment: even not getting your point, but as per my understanding you have to make sure that script is executed successfully or not, for this you can generate logs to make sure it i.e. store output in a temp file.

Comment: Could u plz let me know how can I store logs in a separate file?